# How to calculate for the voltage across resistor R4 and R6 using the operating point values?

Tags: voltage, resistors, dc, resistance

[image]

This is the schematic diagram for the circuit that I need to solve. All I need to know is if it is possible to solve for the voltage across resistor r4 and r6 with all the given operating point values. What is the formula behind it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @MissEngineering Yes it is certainly possible, but did you really have to make a question about this? You even built the circuit in LT Spice so why don't you go ahead and run a simulation and see what you get?

Comment: I mean I already determined the answers but I want to know the equation behind it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs an attempt at a solution, please provide an attempt

Answer (score 2):

I'll just give a hint:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp2XbA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The original circuit redrawn.*

Start redrawing the schematic in a series of simplification steps. Post each step into your question so we can give some guidance if you make any errors.

---

Note that one of the conventions of good schematics is that the voltage, in general, decreases from top to bottom. You can think of V1 as pushing current into the top rail and it flowing down the page to the ground pins. It then becomes very obvious that V<sub>a</sub> > V<sub>b</sub> > V<sub>c</sub>. In general you can expect your readers to read from left to right so it makes sense that signal flow (as in an amplifier, for example, will go from left to right.

If you're interested in developing your skills have a look at [Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics) on this site. A good schematic is a beautiful thing.

Comment: Love it.    Redrawing the circuit into a "readable" format is ALWAYS a great place to start!!!  These textbook questions are intentionally drawn, it seems, to confuse the reader.     The diagram posted here is electrically identical but VASTLY easier to visualize.